# How to store a parameter value in oracle procedure from webservice

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

So what i am looking to do is use a web service call to implement an oracle procedure. To be more specific: I what it so that when i put a value into a parameter in my web service and run it, i want that to be the value sent to the procedure in oracle and then after successfully running to return to the web service as true.

What i have currently tried to to is this:

```
        public bool InsertMachineModels(string MachineModel)
    {
        logger.DebugFormat("FilteredReportInputsDAO.InsertMachineModel({0})", MachineModel);
        bool retVal = true;
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Admin_Utilities.InsertMachineModel", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMachineModel", OracleType.Cursor).Value = Convert.ToString(MachineModel);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (IsErrorLogging)
                        logger.Error("FilteredReportInputsDAO.InsertMachineModels() Exception: ", ex);
                    retVal = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Below you will find my procedure which runs correctly when implemented in sql developer.

```
   procedure InsertMachineModel( pMachineModel in nvarchar2)
    is
    begin
        insert into machine_models (Machine_model) values (pMachineModel);
        commit;

     Exception when others then
      pb_util.logdata(1, 'Admin_utilities.InsertMachineModel', 'Exception thrown', sqlerrm || ' stack ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
      rollback;
      raise;
    end;
```

What i believe to be the problem is this line in the web service:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("pMachineModel", OracleType.Cursor).Value = Convert.ToString(MachineModel);
```

In my logger it says that a cursor must be implemented as a parameterdirection.output parameter however i do not believe in that case you can take a value and send it to the api, but if i am wrong feel free to correct me.

So i guess my question is: If what i believe to be correct in the statement above about parameterdirection is wrong, what is the correct answer?

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to how to implement what i am attempting to do correctly?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("pMachineModel", OracleType.Cursor).Value = 
    Convert.ToString(MachineModel);
```

You're attempting to add a parameter of type `OracleType.Cursor`, which isn't correct or necessary. Try changing the line to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("pMachineModel", OracleType.Char).Value = MachineModel;
```

(There's also no need for `Convert.ToString` here - `MachineModel` is already a `String`).